# Regarding rich text column properties update using pnp js

Tags: multiline-text-field, richhtmlfield

I want to update existing rich text field to enhanced rich text field without losing data in the column using pnp js

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your question? It seems a bit unclear which version of SharePoint you are using and the specific list or library involved. It would be helpful if you could provide some code snippets that you have already tried. This will enable others to better understand your question and provide more targeted assistance.

Comment: here I'm checking in batch edit if particular column is created or not if column is not created we are creating one, here I'm creating with multiline  rich text I want to update the field now from rich text to enhanced rich text. below is the ref code
const fields = await list.fields.get(); 
const fieldNames:string[] = fields.map(f => f.InternalName);
if (fieldNames.indexOf('RichtextInternalName') === -1) {
            list.fields.inBatch(batch)
            .addMultilineText('RichtextInternalName', 6, true, false, false, false);}